# Entity Framework 6 CodeFirst/DatabaseFirst migration data preservation?

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to the ADO .NET technologies. I know EF6 is built on top of ADO .NET. I checked out some of Microsoft's Data technologies reference site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/).

I am trying to figure out if a CodeFirst created database that is modified after initial creation can be  modified and migrated without loss of data. One of the tutorial videos on their site says DatabaseFirst EF mappings created with the entity designer cannot be migrated without loss of data after a change is made to the schema.

Do migrations for changes to schemas based on CodeFirst designs also suffer from that problem of data loss after migration?

Answer (score 3):

This is good article you should read:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

> In the deployment section you saw the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion
>   initializer being used. Code First also provides other initializers,
>   including CreateDatabaseIfNotExists (the default), 
>   DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges (which you used earlier) and
>   DropCreateDatabaseAlways. The DropCreateAlways initializer can be
>   useful for setting up conditions for unit tests. You can also write
>   your own initializers, and you can call an initializer explicitly if
>   you don't want to wait until the application reads from or writes to
>   the database. At the time this tutorial is being written in November,
>   2013, you can only use the Create and DropCreate initializers before
>   you enable migrations. The Entity Framework team is working on making
>   these initializers usable with migrations as well.
>
> For more information about initializers, see Understanding Database
>   Initializers in Entity Framework Code First and chapter 6 of the book
>   Programming Entity Framework: Code First by Julie Lerman and Rowan
>   Miller.
>   quoted from that article.